# Send selected typeahead option through typeahead-on-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-bootstrap, angularjs-bootstrap

```
<input type="text"
       class="topic_select"
       id="selectTopic"
       ng-model="topicsPopulate"
       uib-typeahead="topic.name for topic in topics|filter:$viewValue"
       uib-typeahead-show-hint="true"
       uib-typeahead-min-length="1"
       typeahead-on-select="TopicChanged(topicsPopulate)" />
```

I actually want to send the topic(a json object with many variables) i selected and not the string(topic name) which is stored in `topicsPopulate`.
Topics is an array of topic, and a topic looks like this,

```
{
    id: "12967",
    name: "ABCD",
    description: "ABCD"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uib-typehead` follows the same syntax as Angular `ng-options`. So just alter your `uib-typehead`:

```
uib-typeahead="topic as topic.name for topic in topics|filter:$viewValue"
```

Please look at the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pOTYnY72RuKiG50uEozs?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Initially i used select with ng-options to create this dropdown but had to use typehead for autocomplete feature.

Comment: @KiranKumar Cool :)